# CSS Floats Right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to know the best way to have my header float right so that it's position right next my image.

I've notice that since it's contained inside a div which stetches 100% wide that when I float the title right it goes to the furthest right point of the div rather than next to my image.

I can absolute or relative position my image, but won't that effect the flow? For example when the screen gets to small I would want the header to float under the image.

Is this possible?

```
<div id="holder">
<h1 id="header">My Header goes here</h1>
<img id="feature" src="pic.jpg" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

*style

```
#header{float:right;}
```

Comment: Where is your image supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your container to be 100% width you'll need another 'inner' container that is not 100% width and that contains all the things you want floated to the right:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="innerHolder">
        <h1 id="header">My Header goes here</h1>
        <img id="feature" src="pic.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Style:

```
#holder{width:100%;}
#innerHolder{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to float both the image and the header if you want them next to each other inside the holder div.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is this:

```
<div id="holder">
<img id="feature" src="pic.jpg" alt="" /> 
<h1 id="header">My Header goes here</h1>
</div>
```

and

```
#feature {float: left; width:100}
#header { margin: 0px 0px 0px 110px;}
```

This will float the image, and use the margin of the div to align it to the right of the image.  I just made up values for the width and the margin, but you should get the idea.  If you use float: right, your div will end up on the right side of the browser window, whereas this will let you place the div "to the right" of your image.